# Why does read-only property on my view model goes blank after the postback?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, postback, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

This is an MVC - razor question. [The environment is MVC 4.0.] I have a view model with one editable property and one display-only property. In my view, I am using @html.TextBoxFor() method for the editable property. In order to display the display-only property, I am directly putting @Model.Property. I have a server-side validation on the Editable property and if the posted value for the Editable property is NOT valid, I am returning the same view with the validation error in the validation summary section of the view. Now, here is the problem - After submitting the View form with invalid value for the editable property, I see the error for the editable property, but the display-only property is blank. Does MVC posting BLANK/Nothing for my Display-only property ? How do I get around this issue ?

Comment: You might want to look at how to format for this site, including the use of the backtick to mark text as code. Also, try and spread out your question so it is more readable (and not just a wall of text).

Comment: You are going to have to store it in some sort of field (hidden comes to mind) in order to have it posted back. Or you could write a display template depending on what you are doing.

Comment: @crashmstr, thanks, I will follow that.

Comment: @Mike, Thanks. Yes, I agree. But, why the Display-only property gets updated when I am not posting it ? Does MVC updates all the Model properties on postback whether they are posted or not ? I understand that hidden fields are posted which will resolve this problem. But, my concern is if I have 25 display-only properties, I have to put 25 hidden fields which are posted everytime I hit the web server. Is there any way to tell MVC  to ingore certain View Model properties in the post data ?

Comment: Let me rephrase my last question - is there any way to tell MVC that this perticular View Model property should not be updated when data is posted from client ?

Comment: When you say 'not be updated' do you mean not be posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to exclude view model attributes you can use a combination of the Bind Attribute and an interface with just the properties you want to include when model binding on the server.

See here: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=439

Answer (score 1):

If you are not keeping it the property on a form field(Input etc..), It won't be availbale when you post it.

Use `@Html.HiddenFor` method keep the property (along with displaying it) in your form so that it will be available when you post it.

```
@model YourCustomerViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  <span>@Model.EmailAddress</span>
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.FirstName)

  @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.EmailAddress)
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```